# Get data and inner data from accordion

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, foreach

i'm trying to make an accordion that loads user data from two different tables but i can't seem to make it work.

To understand what i mean i have a snippet what i want to achieve:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion loading user data</h2>

<button class="accordion">John Doe</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>FTP Host: domain.com</p>
  <p>FTP Username: johndoe</p>
  <p>FTP Password: test123</p>
  <hr>
  <p>FTP Host: second-domain.com</p>
  <p>FTP Username: johndoe</p>
  <p>FTP Password: test123</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Jack Pepperidge</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>FTP Host: domain.com</p>
  <p>FTP Username: jacky</p>
  <p>FTP Password: test123</p>
  <hr>
  <p>FTP Host: second-domain.com</p>
  <p>FTP Username: jacky</p>
  <p>FTP Password: test123</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Sam Parker</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>FTP Host: domain.com</p>
  <p>FTP Username: sammy</p>
  <p>FTP Password: test123</p>
  <hr>
  <p>FTP Host: second-domain.com</p>
  <p>FTP Username: sammy</p>
  <p>FTP Password: test123</p>
</div>
```

I have two tables named customers and customers_details

| customers | customers_details |
| --- | --- |
| customer_id | ftp_host |
| customer_name | ftp_username |
| customer_company | ftp_password |
|  | customer_id |

Now the issue that i run is that i have this script:

```
                    <?php
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT customers.customer_id, customers.customer_name, customers.customer_company, customers_details.ftp_host, customers_details.ftp_username, customers_details.ftp_password
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN customers_details ON customers.customer_id = customers_details.customer_id WHERE customers.customer_id > ?
ORDER BY customers.customer_company ASC");
    $biggerThan = 0;
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $biggerThan);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $customer_company = $row['customer_company'];
            $customer_name = $row['customer_name'];
            $customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
            $rows[] = $row;
?>
    <button class="accordion">John Doe</button>
    <div class="panel">
<?php
                    foreach ($rows as $row) {
                        // FTP details
                        $ftp_host = htmlentities($row['ftp_host']);
                        $ftp_username = htmlentities($row['ftp_username']);
                        $ftp_password = htmlentities($row['ftp_password']);
                        ?>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>FTP Host: <?= $ftp_host; ?></p>
      <p>FTP Username: <?= $ftp_username; ?></p>
      <p>FTP Password: <?= $ftp_password; ?></p>
      <hr>
      <p>FTP Host: <?= $ftp_host ?></p>
      <p>FTP Username: <?= $ftp_username; ?></p>
      <p>FTP Password: <?= $ftp_password; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
                   }
}

} else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">No user details found</div>';
}
?>
```

But when i run it i get

John Doe 
John Doe 
Jack Pepperidge 
Jack Pepperidge 
Sam Parker 
Sam Parker

I tried changing the statement with UNION but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your example code is missing a curly: `}`. Either `while` or `foreach`.

Comment: How many rows in the `customers_details` table for each customer? ... Are you sure?

Comment: This: `$rows[] = $row;` and then this: `foreach ($rows as $row) {` doesn't make sense to me. Apparently within a single `while` loop you're appending an element to array `$rows` then looping on that array...? What am I missing?

Comment: Please boil down the code your are showing to the necessary minimum next time. We know what an accordion is, and all the JS & CSS you are showing us relating to that, seems to be highly irrelevant to the actual problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

First query the database, using `SELECT DISTINCT` to make sure you're only getting a single row per customer. Then loop on the results and write your `<button class="accordion">` and `<div class="panel">` for each customer:

```php
<?php

// added SELECT DISTINCT to ensure a single row per customer
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT customers.customer_id, customers.customer_name, customers.customer_company, customers_details.ftp_host, customers_details.ftp_username, customers_details.ftp_password
FROM customers LEFT JOIN customers_details ON customers.customer_id = customers_details.customer_id WHERE customers.customer_id > ?
ORDER BY customers.customer_company ASC");

$biggerThan = 0;
$stmt->bind_param("i", $biggerThan);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $customer_company = $row['customer_company'];
        $customer_name = $row['customer_name'];
        $customer_id = $row['customer_id'];

        // removed $rows[] = $row;

?>
    <button class="accordion"><?= $customer_company; ?></button>
    <div class="panel">

<?php

        // removed foreach ($rows as $row) {
        // $row already contains the fields:
        //   customer_id, customer_name, customer_company,
        //   ftp_host, ftp_username, ftp_password

        // FTP details
        $ftp_host = htmlentities($row['ftp_host']);
        $ftp_username = htmlentities($row['ftp_username']);
        $ftp_password = htmlentities($row['ftp_password']);

?>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>FTP Host: <?= $ftp_host; ?></p>
      <p>FTP Username: <?= $ftp_username; ?></p>
      <p>FTP Password: <?= $ftp_password; ?></p>
      <hr>
      <p>FTP Host: <?= $ftp_host ?></p>
      <p>FTP Username: <?= $ftp_username; ?></p>
      <p>FTP Password: <?= $ftp_password; ?></p>
    </div>

<?php

    } // END WHILE $row
} // END IF $num_rows

} else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">No user details found</div>';
}

?>
```